# R manipulating data for some value of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Consider the following data:

[image]

I want to aggregate some rows based on a condition.
The condition is group "A2" and "A3" are same. So I want to calculate sum of variables (Fo,JA and KH) of these groups based on year and month. So the expected output is as follows:

[image]

Here is the data:

```
#R code
df1<-data.frame(V=rep( paste("A",1:3,sep=""),each=12),
year=rep(c(2020,2021),each=6,len=36),
month=rep(c(1:3),each=2,len=36),
Fo=1:36,JA=36:1,KH=c(1:12,12:1,21:32))
df1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the value of 'A2' and 'A3' group to 'A23' and take sum of different columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(V = replace(V, V %in% c('A2', 'A3'), 'A23'), year, month) %>%
  summarise(across(Fo:KH, sum))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have  too many columns(instead three Fo:KH, How can hnadle it in across function?

Comment: How are the columns structured? `Fo:KH` consists of columns from `Fo` to `KH`, you can change that to `A:Z`. There are also functions like `starts_with`, `contains` which may help you to select columns.